# Camera wont turn with cv2.VideoCapture(0).release()

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv

I made this script:

```
import cv2
import pyaudio
import wave
import threading
import time
import subprocess
import os
import keyboard

class VideoRecorder():  
    # Video class based on openCV 
    def __init__(self):
        self.open = True
        self.fps = 6               # fps should be the minimum constant rate at which the camera can
        self.fourcc = "MJPG"       # capture images (with no decrease in speed over time; testing is required)
        self.frameSize = (640,480) # video formats and sizes also depend and vary according to the camera used
        self.video_filename = "temp_video.avi"
        self.video_cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        self.video_writer = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*self.fourcc)
        self.video_out = cv2.VideoWriter(self.video_filename, self.video_writer, self.fps, self.frameSize)
        self.frame_counts = 1
        self.start_time = time.time()

    # Video starts being recorded 
    def record(self):
        timer_start = time.time()
        timer_current = 0

        while(self.open==True):
            ret, video_frame = self.video_cap.read()

            if self.frame_counts > 10:
                break

            if (ret==True):
                self.video_out.write(video_frame)
                self.frame_counts += 1
                print self.frame_counts
                time.sleep(0.16)

            else:
                #threading.Thread(target=self.stop).start()
                break

                # 0.16 delay -> 6 fps
        time.sleep(1)
        self.video_out.release()
        cv2.VideoCapture(0).release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        dwhuiadhuiahdwia = raw_input("Testtidhwuia?")


    # Finishes the video recording therefore the thread too
    def stop(self):
        print "You made it"
        if self.open==True:

            self.open=False
            self.video_out.release()
            self.video_cap.release()
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            hduwahduiwahdiu = raw_input("Press enter to continue...")

        else: 
            pass


    # Launches the video recording function using a thread        
    def start(self):
        video_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.record)
        video_thread.start()

def start_video_recording():

    global video_thread

    video_thread = VideoRecorder()
    video_thread.start()

def stop_AVrecording():

    frame_counts = video_thread.frame_counts
    elapsed_time = time.time() - video_thread.start_time
    recorded_fps = frame_counts / elapsed_time
    print "total frames " + str(frame_counts)
    print "elapsed time " + str(elapsed_time)
    print "recorded fps " + str(recorded_fps)
    video_thread.stop()

    # Makes sure the threads have finished
    time.sleep(1)
    video_thread.stop()

    print ".."

start_video_recording()
duiwhaiudhwauidhwa = raw_input("hello")
```

It should record a video with the camera for about 10 seconds, then save it and then turn off the camera and close the script when the user presses enter.

But it doesn't really work.

It will record a video, and it does save the video but the camera only turns off when I close the script (the camera is on, but isn't recording.)

I know this because the led next to my camera doesn't turn off when I'm prompted to press enter to continue, but does when I press enter and the script closes.

I found [this,](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/12301) and I haven't tested it yet. But if I were to use that solution and it worked, I'd have to do it on every computer I run the script on manually.